# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportDataProvider'

Tags: wffm

We are working an an existing Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 151003) solution.
Seems like the WFFM got upgraded but isn't perfect. So we are trying to reinstall WFFM.

But facing below issue on local dev machine:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportDataProvider'.

Its a single server and Sitecore.Analytics.reporting is disabled.

Any clue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment you below from  **SwitchMasterToweb.config**:

```
<reporting>
  <dataProvider>
    <datasources>
      <add key="item">
        <FiltersFactory>
          <param desc="definitionDatabaseName">web</param>
        </FiltersFactory>
      </add>
      <add key="collection">
        <FiltersFactory>
          <param desc="definitionDatabaseName">web</param>
        </FiltersFactory>
      </add>
      <add key="reporting">
        <FiltersFactory>
          <param desc="definitionDatabaseName">web</param>
        </FiltersFactory>
      </add>
    </datasources>
  </dataProvider>
</reporting>
```

Please have a look on commments: https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2016/02/sitecore-wffm-error-sitecoreanalyticsre.html

Comment: This file is disabled locally. There is no point in commenting it out I guess